# adding/removing objects to a list in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have a list of objects called gobletinv that i want to add and remove objects from
right now to add a new object I've just done this

```
       gobletinv(gobletpointer).mainstattype = MST.Text
            gobletinv(gobletpointer).mainstatvalue = MSV.Text
            gobletinv(gobletpointer).substat1type = ST1.Text
            gobletinv(gobletpointer).substat1value = SV1.Text
            gobletinv(gobletpointer).substat2type = ST2.Text
            gobletinv(gobletpointer).substat2value = SV2.Text
            gobletinv(gobletpointer).substat3type = ST3.Text
            gobletinv(gobletpointer).substat3value = SV3.Text
            gobletinv(gobletpointer).substat4type = ST4.Text
            gobletinv(gobletpointer).substat4value = SV4.Text
            gobletpointer += 1
```

i currently have no idea how i would remove an object from this list

Comment: This isn't adding objects to the list, this is modifying the values of objects already in the list. Take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=net-6.0) and make not of the methods for `Add` and `Remove`. What you are doing is accessing an existing element at index `gobletpointer` as seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.item?view=net-6.0).

Comment: "i have a list of objects called gobletinv" --> It really depends on what you mean by "list" and "objects".  Is this an `Array`, or an actual `List(Of Something)`? This matters! How did you declare `gobletinv`? Are you pre-populating `gobletinv` with instances of some `Class`?...or are the things within a `Structure`? The answers to these questions will have a HUGE affect on the correct approach to your problem...

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the type your collection holds is called `Stat`. Let's also assume that `gobletpointer` is an Integer with an initial value of 0.

Each line where you are referencing the collection, you start it off with:

```vb
gobletinv(gobletpointer)
```

What this does is get the item from the collection at a given index.

So right now when you set the various property values to their respective TextBox value, you are overwriting the existing item in the collection.

If you wanted to add a new item to the collection, you would use the Add method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add)). For example:

```vb
gobletinv.Add(New Stat() With {
    mainstattype = MST.Text,
    mainstatvalue = MSV.Text
    substat1type = ST1.Text,
    substat1value = SV1.Text,
    substat2type = ST2.Text,
    substat2value = SV2.Text,
    substat3type = ST3.Text,
    substat3value = SV3.Text,
    substat4type = ST4.Text,
    substat4value = SV4.Text
})
```

Now if you wanted to remove the object from the collection, it depends on how you want to remove it. But here is an example of leveraging the RemoveAt method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat)) to remove the first record from the collection:

```vb
gobletinv.RemoveAt(0)
```

Update: This is a fiddle demonstrating how to add/remove items to the collection. https://dotnetfiddle.net/c0W6yS